# Group by time with interval in SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, time, group-by, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have the data that I need to group by Time with 2 minutes interval. My data looks like this:

```
id            time             action_name            url
111      2020-09-01-09:19:00     First           www.stackoverflow/a12345
111      2020-09-01-09:19:04     Midpoint        www.stackoverflow/a12345
111      2020-09-01-09:19:08     Third           www.stackoverflow/a12345
112      2020-09-01-10:12:05     First           www.someotherurl/a111111
111      2020-09-01-12:36:54     First           www.stackoverflow/a12345
111      2020-09-01-12:36:58     Midpoint        www.stackoverflow/a12345
111      2020-09-01-12:37:03     Third           www.stackoverflow/a12345
111      2020-09-01-12:37:09     Complete        www.stackoverflow/a12345
222      2020-09-01-15:17:44     First           www.stackoverflow/a2222
222      2020-09-01-15:17:48     Midpoint        www.stackoverflow/a2222
222      2020-09-01-15:18:05     Third           www.stackoverflow/a2222
```

I need to grab the data with the following condition: if `x_id` and `x_url` has `Complete` value for `action_name` column, grab that. If it doesn't have `Complete` then grab `Third` and so on. The code that I have at the moment returns only one row per `x_id` and `x_url`. So not only I need to group the data by `id` and `url` but also by time, with interval of 2 minties. Below is the code:

```
SELECT AS VALUE 
  ARRAY_AGG(current_query_result 
    ORDER BY CASE action_name
      WHEN 'Complete' THEN 1
      WHEN 'Third' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Midpoint' THEN 3
      WHEN 'First' THEN 4
    END
    LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM (
  SELECT
    c.time,
    c.id,
    c.action_name, 
    c.url
  FROM `bq_table` c
  WHERE c.action_name in ('First', 'Midpoint', 'Third', 'Complete')
) current_query_result
GROUP BY id, url
```

Desired output is:

```
id            time             action_name            url
111      2020-09-01-09:19:08     Third           www.stackoverflow/a12345
112      2020-09-01-10:12:05     First           www.someotherurl/a111111
111      2020-09-01-12:37:09     Complete        www.stackoverflow/a12345
222      2020-09-01-15:18:05     Third           www.stackoverflow/a2222
```

I have tried this: `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(2*60 * DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(c.time), 2*60)) timekey`but got an error: `No matching signature for function UNIX_SECONDS for argument types: STRING. Supported signature: UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t 
    ORDER BY STRPOS('First,Midpoint,Third,Complete',action_name) DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.bq_table` t
WHERE action_name IN ('First', 'Midpoint', 'Third', 'Complete')
GROUP BY id, url, 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time), 
    INTERVAL MOD(UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time)), 2 * 60) 
    SECOND
  )
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.bq_table` AS (
  SELECT 111 id, '2020-09-01-09:19:00' time, 'First' action_name, 'www.stackoverflow/a12345' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-09:19:04', 'Midpoint', 'www.stackoverflow/a12345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-09:19:08', 'Third', 'www.stackoverflow/a12345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 112, '2020-09-01-10:12:05', 'First', 'www.someotherurl/a111111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:36:54', 'First', 'www.stackoverflow/a12345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:36:58', 'Midpoint', 'www.stackoverflow/a12345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:37:03', 'Third', 'www.stackoverflow/a12345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:37:09', 'Complete', 'www.stackoverflow/a12345' 
)
SELECT 
  AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t 
    ORDER BY STRPOS('First,Midpoint,Third,Complete',action_name) DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.bq_table` t
WHERE action_name IN ('First', 'Midpoint', 'Third', 'Complete')
GROUP BY id, url, 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time), 
    INTERVAL MOD(UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time)), 2 * 60) 
    SECOND
  )
```

with output

```
Row     id      time                    action_name     url  
1       111     2020-09-01-09:19:08     Third           www.stackoverflow/a12345     
2       112     2020-09-01-10:12:05     First           www.someotherurl/a111111     
3       111     2020-09-01-12:37:09     Complete        www.stackoverflow/a12345
```

Comment: I just edited the question. I have added `id 222` to the data and to the desired output. Code as it is right now returns both `Midpoint` (time: `2020-09-01-15:17:48`) and `Third` (time: `2020-09-01-15:18:05`), wherein fact I need only `Third` to be returned. So 2 minutes interval doesn't seem to work here, or rather this method is not what I need for the specific problem. How can I filter 1 or 2 minutes interval of the CHAIN `First`, `Midpoint`, etc... Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: based on what you showed in `I have tried this` section of your question - I assumed you just wanted to group by each 2 min - which as I see now is obviously not what you meant - I would recommend you to post new question and very clearly identify your use case - so there will be no misinterpretation

Comment: yes, I was thinking the same thing, this is an entirely new question. I will post one. I did mean 2 minutes interval in my post though, but I just discovered, that it is not what my data needs, you know how it is :)  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close to solve it, you just need to use PARSE_TIMESTAMP to convert the string into TIMESTAMP type, e.g.

```sql
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', '2020-09-01-09:19:00')
```

Outputs:

```
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2020-09-01 09:19:00 |
+---------------------+
```